# Como puedo llamar una clase como en un json en c++?

Tags: c++, json

en javascript cuando llamo a una funcion hago lo siguiente

```js
let json={
    "test":function(){
    console.log("adsf");
    }
}
json["test"]()
```

quisiera hacer eso con c++ pero no se como hacerlo

```cpp
class clase{
   public:
     void test(){
     cout << "asdf";

     }
 
};
int main(){
    clase t;
    t["test"]();  
    cout << "Hola mundo" <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

se agradeceria mucho la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

C++ y JavaScript son dos lenguajes diferentes, cada uno con sus propias reglas y restricciones. Tu idea podría implementarse en C++, pero no es el camino adecuado.

Me explico.

Tu pretendes crear un mapa de funciones, esto se podría implementar facilmente así:

```
void hola()
{ std::cout << "hola\n"; }

void adios()
{ std::cout << "adios\n"; }

std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> mapa { {"hola", hola}, {"adios", adios} };

mapa["hola"]();
mapa["adios"]();
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando [aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1ZKqb23Xebid2m7B)

Lo que sucede es que este ejemplo tiene ciertas contrapartidas... como ves, la interfaz de la función se define al declarar la variable `mapa`, es decir, todas las funciones que pretendas almacenar en esta variable deben tener la misma interfaz, en este caso `void()`,  es decir, no admiten parámetros y no devuelven nada.

**¿Y por qué en JavaScript si se puede?**

Pues resulta que hay una diferencia importante entre ambos lenguajes: C++ es un lenguaje de tipado fuerte mientras que JavaScript no posee tipado alguno.

Es facil ver cómo una variable de JavaScript acepta lo que le echen:

```
a = 1;
a = "otra cosa";
a = 3.25;
```

Sin embargo en C++ esto no es posible. En C++ cada variable tiene su tipo y dicho tipo limita el rango de posibles valores que puede almacenarse en esa variable.

Si bien el tipado débil aporta mucha flexibilidad a la hora de programar, también añade mucha incertidumbre, ya que no puedes garantizar que una variable sea del tipo X y puede, básicamente, ser cualquier cosa. Por otro lado el tipado fuerte te garantiza que una variable **siempre** va a ser del tipo que te están indicando.

En C++ la forma estándar de implementar clases es la siguiente:

```
class Clase
{
public:
    void test()
    { std::cout << "hola mundo\n"; }
};

Clase objeto;
objeto.test();
```